# Spectral sequence for two fibrations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Given maps of fibrations, i.e. commutative diagrams of smooth manifolds

$$\begin{matrix} 
\ F & \to & E &\to & B \\\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\\  
\ F' & \to & E' &\to & B' 
\end{matrix}$$

where each horizontal is a fiber bundle. Vertical arrows induce isomorphisms for de Rham cohomology $H_{dR}^{*}(F') \to H_{dR}^{*}(F)$ and $H_{dR}^{*}(B') \to H_{dR}^{*}(B)$. I'm trying to obtain that $H_{dR}^{*}(E') \to H_{dR}^{*}(E)$ is also an isomorphism.

I think I need to use Leray-Serre spectral sequence for solving this problem. I tried to go to the real cohomology for these smooth manifolds (Since de Rham theorem states that de Rham cohomology $H^{*}_{dR}(X)$ of a smooth manifold $X$ (without boundary) is isomorphic to the real cohomology $H^{*}(X,R)$ ).

There are properties of naturality:

such that the fiber over $b \in B$ maps to the fiber over $f(b)\in B'$, we get maps $E^{p,q}_{r} → E'^{p,q}_{r}$ (including the case $r={\infty}$) which respect all differentials and isomorphisms.

The map $\widetilde{f}^{∗}:H^{*}(E;R)→H^{*}(E';R)$ preserves filtrations, inducing a map on successive quotient groups which is the map $f_{\infty}^{∗}$.

Also it's known that $E_2^{p,q} = H^p(B,H^q(F,R))$ for $p,q \geq 0$

Similar to what was done by Allen Hatcher in his book "Spectral Sequences in Algebraic Topology' (chapter 1 page 20). I made the following.

Since for Principal Ideal Domain $R$ we have isomorphisms $H^p(B,H^q(F,R)) \to H^p(B',H^q(F',R))$. The map $f^2$ between $E_2$ terms is an isomorphism. $f^2$ induces $f^3$ and so on, the maps $f^r$ are all isomorphisms, and in particular $f^{\infty}$ is an isomorphism. The map $H^{*}(E;R) \to H^{*}(E';R)$ preserves filtrations and induces the isomorphisms $f^{\infty}$ between successive quotients in the filtrations, so it follows by induction and the five-lemma that it restricts to an isomorphism on each term $F^n_{p}$ in the filtration of $H^{*}(E;R)$, and in particular on $H^{*}(E;R)$ itself.

My first question. Am I right in my solution? If I'm not right may you explain this question in more details?

My second question is there any way to solve this problem directly without transition to the real cohomology of these manifolds?

Thank you!

Comment: You phrase this as an exercise, is it?

Comment: @Fernando Muro. I'm starting learning spectral sequences.Possibly it seems as an exercise. It's interesting for me what's happened for de Rham cohomology. Possibly there are direct more advanced approaches for solving this problem. And I decided to ask this question there. Am I right in my solution? Or not? Thank you

Comment: I’d say you must assume the base is simply connected.

Comment: @Fernando Muro. Yes you are right base is simply connected and the fiber  is a path connected. But in any case I'm not sure in my solution

Comment: indeed, a map between convergent spectral sequences which induces an isomorphism at some page also induces an isomorphism between the limits.

Comment: @Fernando Muro. Am I right? If I'm not may you explain please? Thank you